# Is it possible to intercept all DataNucleus' JDO SQL queries?

Tags: java, sql, jdo, datanucleus, intercept

Assuming one has an operational Java application using DataNucleus's implementation of JDO to access a database, is it possible to intercept all SQL queries made to the database? The intention is to run statistics on them and keep a log/trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may easily get logs of all SQL statements from DataNucleus by turning on the category DataNucleus.Datastore.Native (see http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/logging.html)

JDO2 InstanceLifecycleListeners would allow you to intercept events, but I don't think the SQL statements would be available there...

You can also look to your app server for SQL profiling tools. For example GlassFish allows you to attach SQLTraceListener implementations to your connection pools. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/giyck.html#giygg

Comment: is it possible to intercept query object load (instantiation) using an InstanceLifecycleListener? I'm using the LoadLifecycleListener, but it does not catch the querys! :\

Answer (score 0):

## Log4j

You can use [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) or [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) with DataNucleus. I'm going to tell about Log4j configuration.

> log4j.properties

```
# Define the destination and format of our logging
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{1}:%M:%L - %m%n

# DataNucleus Categories
log4j.category.DataNucleus=ALL
```

The last line assigns a level threshold to INFO or ALL in order to see all DataNucleus logs. DataNucleus uses a series of **categories**, and logs all messages to these categories. [See here](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/logging.html) for more details. You probably need

- `log4j.category.DataNucleus.Query` - All messages relating to queries
- `log4j.category.DataNucleus.Datastore` - All general datastore messages
  or
- `log4j.category.DataNucleus.JDO` - All messages general to JDO

`log4j.category.DataNucleus` is a root of all DataNucleus log categories.

Add [log4j](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22log4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22log4j%22) to your CLASSPATH. I use [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) for dependency management, so here is my build script:

> build.gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
}

dependencies {
    // Logging
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.+'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.+'
    runtime ('log4j:log4j:1.2.17') {
        exclude group: "com.sun.jdmk", module: "jmxtools"
        exclude group: "com.sun.jmx", module: "jmxri"
        exclude group: "javax.mail", module: "mail"
        exclude group: "javax.jms", module: "jms"
    }    
}
```

To provide a Log4J configuration file when starting up your application set a JVM parameter as

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties
```

This may be done for you if you are running within a JavaEE application server. Or if you are using Spring WebMVC, place log4j.properties inside WEB-INF, and add the following listener to your Deployment descriptor.

> web.xml

```xml
<!-- The definition of the Log4j Configuration -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```